# How to overlay TextView on Button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

My XML code is:

```
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="right">
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMyDeals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="DEALS"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_deals_button"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge_notification_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
    android:text="23"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />




</RelativeLayout>
```

I want `TextView` bubble which is a notification badge to float over the `Button`. `TextView` may float over top right or top left corner of `Button`.
How to do it?

Comment: how? can you make one? I will accept that answer

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right">

   <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMyDeals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:text="DEALS"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge_notification_2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
    android:text="23"
    android:textColor="#FFF"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:translationZ="5dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

Use `FrameLayout` instead.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnMyDeals"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:text="DEALS"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/badge_notification_2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@android:drawable/ic_notification_overlay"
            android:text="23"
            android:textColor="#FFF"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:elevation="100dp"
            />

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: not working for me, button is overlapping on textview.

Comment: it will not work on API <21 as both translationtoZ and elevation attributes are not supported.

Answer (score 1):

hey I had the same problem unfortunately, I can't see any logical reason why it shouldn't work as expected, it seems like a bug.

The only way I could work around it was to have the text on top of the button be in the top level view hierarchy

```
<FrameLayout>
    <LinearLayout regular layout with button inside/>
    <TextTiew for button overlay />
</FrameLayout>
```

not pretty, not efficient but works.

Comment: It's not a bug, but a Material design. Button and a TextView have different elevations

Answer (score 0):

use `android:layout_alignEnd` to align top right and `android:layout_alignStart` to align top left. you can put in 'place' of 'start' and 'right' in place of 'end' for lower apis.

`android:layout_alignEnd="@id/btnMyDeals"`

OR

`android:layout_alignStart="@id/btnMyDeals"`

put these lines for your textview

Comment: not working for me, button is overlapping on textview.

Comment: No idea then. I tried your layout on my system with `android:layout_alignStart` and it worked for me. You can also add `android:layout_alignTop="@id/btnMyDeals"` with the previous thing to your textview.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `android:layout_gravity="top|right"` or `android:layout_gravity="top|left"` to your `TextView`

```
  <FrameLayout
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnMyDeals"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    ...
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/badge_notification_2"
    ...
    android:layout_gravity="top|right"
    />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I can see half textview but rest half is overlapped by button, I want textview floating over button.  Can you please recheck the code?

Comment: @Ritzor now half of textview float the button right?

Comment: yes? actually that button is overlapping textview. I want reverse

Answer (score 0):

To overlay a button with a textView,
this works for me. But I don't know how low the API-Level can be.

```
android:elevation="8dp"
```